# Not able to set permission in Android 7.0.0

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, android-permissions

Not able to set permission in Android 7.0.0. App launch sets Camera ,Location, storage ,calendar permissions which is not working in Android os ver >6. Please help.
I tried below link example but no luck
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android
Permissions section.

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

There is currently (Ti SDK 6.0.2.GA) a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23429) and an open [Github pull request](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/8706) about Nougat permissions. Might be worth following that ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the permissions in **tiapp.xml** in **android manifest**, see the below permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

**Good Luck, Cheers**